# asdf packages installed by a plugin (example golang)

Tags: asdf, asdf-vm

I'm not sure how this works, but I have this scenario:

- Installed `asdf`;
- Installed plugin `golang`;
- Installed golang `1.20.4`;
- Then installed a go package using `go install moul.io/assh/v2@latest`;
- This package gave me the `assh` shim binary;
- Now I have updated the golang installation to `1.20.5`;

The scenario here is that the `assh` package is still on the `golang 1.20.4`.
So, if I uninstall this version, I will lose all my packages, right?
Which is the right way to deal with those "sub-packages" installed with which version?

Cheers
Vitor Jr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have an [open issue (#1021)](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/1021) that describes a `migrate` subcommand that would copy those "sub-packages" from one version of a tool to another. But nothing is currently implemented that allows for that.

So the "solution" is either to reinstall the packages when you update versions, or do not delete the old versions of the language. If the feature described in #1021 is interesting to you, feel free to upvote it so we can gauge interest.